# Why Swift throws error when using optional param in closure func?

Tags: swift

Can someone explain why the swift compiler complains about the "offset:" parameter which is optional anyway?

If I pass zero as param `incrementByFive(0)` then it works. But why would I bother doing so when I have a default value in closure definition...

[code and its error image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK1qI.png)
Here's the code:

```
func makeIncrementer(amount: Int) -> (Int?) -> Int {
    var counter = 0

    func incrementer(_ offset: Int? = 0) -> Int {
        counter += amount + offset!
        return counter
    }

    return incrementer
}


let incrementByFive = makeIncrementer(amount: 5)
incrementByFive()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *functions* can have default parameters in Swift, but not closures.

The closure returned from `makeIncrementer()` has the type 
`(Int?) -> Int`, i.e. it takes one argument of type `Int?`,
and that must be provided when calling the closure.

Compare also [SR-531 Allow default parameters in closure parameters](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-531), in particular the comment

> Doesn't really make sense, if you need this behavior you should be using a function. Closures are usually called anonymously with their arguments all provided, so there is no need for default parameter values.

Comment: I'm learning swift, so it was just a test.
thank you! understood.