# Getting a reference to an instance variable with a default parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, function, default-parameters

So given the following code, how does one get a reference to a function that takes a parameter with a default value and invoke the reference with the default value?

```
class Test {
  func doIt() { print("Done") }
  func doIt(_ adjective: String = "better") {
    print("Done \(adjective)")
  }
}


let t = Test()
let fn1 = t.doIt as () -> Void
let fn2 = t.doIt as (String) -> Void

fn1() // Works
fn2() // Does not work; requires parameter
```

I also tried the following

```
let fn2 = t.doIt as (String?) -> Void
```

But that also does not work. Any ideas? I'd like to invoke `fn2()` and get the printed result `"Done better"`

Comment: `fn2` is a closure, and closures cannot have default values for their parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Swift throws error when using optional param in closure func?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45258621/1187415)

Answer (score 0):

I think you already got what you wanted, a reference to that function.

Since the type is  `(String) -> Void`, it expects `String` as an input. So you have to pass it to call.