# Swift: Why does a function returned from another function can't have default values?

Tags: swift, closures

Let's say we have a function with defalut parameter values:

```swift
// function with default parameter values
func a(m:Int = 0, n:Int = 1) {
  print(m, n)
}

a()         // 0 1
a(m:2)      // 2 1
a(n:3)      // 0 3
a(m:4, n:5) // 4 5
```

Now I want to return exactly the same function from another function:

```swift
func b() -> (Int,Int)->Void {
  func a(m:Int = 0, n:Int = 1) {
    print(m, n)
  }
  return a    // function returned
}

let a2 = b()

a2(m:4, n:5)  // ⛔ error: extraneous argument labels 'm:n:'
a2(4)         // ⛔ error: missing argument for parameter #2  
a2(4,5)       // OK
```

Now, neither can I use argument labels nor can I use default values for parameters, why?

It seems that function `a2()` is a totally different thing from function `a()`, what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Closures cannot have default values (and no external parameter names). I am fairly sure that this has been asked and answered before. Still searching ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613272/xcode-8-function-types-cannot-have-argument-label-breaking-my-build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45258621/1187415: “Only functions can have default parameters”